# How to split time intervals by day in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns some device state information with device id and timestamp. I am trying to do some daily reports and for that I need to know what state devices were in during the day. So, for example, my query might get me something like this

```
device id     start              end                state
---------------------------------------------------------
1             2017-01-01 13:38   2017-01-03 12:47   1
2             2017-01-01 03:15   2017-01-02 11:04   1
... more records for devices including devices 1 and 2 ...
```

what I want to end up with is

```
device id     start              end                state
---------------------------------------------------------
1             2017-01-01 13:38   2017-01-01 23:59   1
1             2017-01-02 00:00   2017-01-02 23:59   1
1             2017-01-03 00:00   2017-01-03 12:47   1
2             2017-01-01 03:15   2017-01-01 23:59   1
2             2017-01-02 00:00   2017-01-02 11:04   1
```

What I tried, is something like this

```
select
    l.device_id,
    gs.ts as "day",
    case when l.start < gs.ts then gs.ts else l.start end as start,
    case when l.end > gs.ts + '1 day'::interval then gs.ts + '1 day'::interval else l.end end as end,
    l.state
from ( ... my query goes here ... ) as l
right join
    (select generate_series(
        date 'start date',
        date 'end date',
        '1 day'::interval)) as gs(ts)
    on ((gs.ts, gs.ts + '1 day'::interval) overlaps (l.start, l.end))
order by l.device_id, l.start
```

Essentially, I right join a sequence of days using overlap function, so every interval that overlaps with that day generates a row and then I cut intervals at the day borders.

Then I use this as a nested select for my daily calculations.

The problem with this approach is that the right join generates a lot of records and the join filter then takes forever. Here is a piece of `explain analyze` output

```
->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=5371.28..3149290.69 rows=11525332 width=32) (actual time=228.799..32849.000 rows=41197 loops=1)
Join Filter: ... the generate sequence stuff removed for brevity...
Rows Removed by Join Filter: 4994476
```

As you can see, it generated about 5 million rows, filtered them down to 41K rows and the operation took some 32 seconds.

Is there a more efficient solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be faster than your current approach:

```
select q.device_id,
       generate_series(start::date, end::date, interval '1 day') as day,
       end as day,
       state
from (your query here) q;
```

You can use a subquery to get the exact date/times that you want.

Comment: So, this would generate a whole sequence for each record. How do I split the records up at day breaks then?

Comment: @MadWombat . . . If you run this on a sample of data, you will see that Postgres generates a separate row for each day.

Comment: I see. And then I use a where clause to filter it down, so only days that overlap between start and end remain?

Comment: @MadWombat . . . You shouldn't need additional filtering.  This should generate the rows you want.  You *do* need some additional logic to work out the rules for the exact dates/times you want to show.

Comment: Ah! I was confused about start and end of the sequence. Looks like I still need my `case when` statements to set end and start correctly

Comment: Wow! Awesome, just went from 30+ seconds to about 2.